# Why do I need to import driver to use lifted queries?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm using slick 2.0 for my interaction with the database.

As recommended I've added external connection pool using BonesCP.

```
val driver =  Class.forName(Database.driver)
val ds = new BoneCPDataSource(); 
ds.setJdbcUrl(Database.jdbcUri);        
ds.setUsername(Database.user);  
ds.setPassword(Database.password);
```

using it I've created my connection:

```
scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database.forDataSource(ds)
    db withSession {implicit  session =>
         (...)
    }
  }
```

Now if I do on my `TableQuery` object something like this:

`provisioning.foreach {(...)}`

it says that there is no foreach method.

So I've imported:
`import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._`

and now everything works well.

What I don't like is that my code is tied to a certain database implementation.

Can I somehow make it read the "db dialect" from the config file?

Answer (score 0):

So now I know how this should be done properly.
I've been to a presentation by Stefan Zeiger on Slick who is the original author of the library and he pointed out that since `PostgresDriver` as well as other drivers is a trait we can mixin it instead of importing. Thus having chance to dynamically choose the driver that fits our database.